# Coloring the integers with red, blue, and green

Tags: combinatorics

Can all integers can be painted either red, blue, or green such that there exists at least $1$ integer of each color, and if any $3$ integers $a$, $b$, and $c$ have the same color then $a+b$, $a+c$, $b+c$, and $a+b+c$ also have the same colour?

Comment: @Zubzub  $\{1,4,7\}$ are blue but $1+4$ is green and $1+4+7$ is red.

Comment: I assume the question is for all integers?  Not just the non-negative ones.  Otherwise, $0$=red, $1$=blue, $>1$=green.

Comment: Sorry I said garbage :x

Comment: @lulu Whether or not that works depends on whether $a, b$ and $c$ have to be distinct.  If not, $a = b = c$ implies all positive integers should be blue.

Comment: @Shagnik  You're right about that. I was assuming they were distinct, but that requirement isn't stated anywhere.

Answer (score 3):

You want the red, blue and green sets to be closed under addition.  Can you partition the integers into such sets?

Big hint:

> Consider the signs of the integers.

Comment: So ya.. If I colour 0 as one, all negative integers with the second colour and all positive with the third colour. I am done. Isn't it?

Comment: @Daanish: Yes, that’s right.